# Countif With Multiple OR Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to count the number of cells in a column which contain a specific value. I am currently using the following code:

`iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("A:A"), "SAL")`

However, I now need to count how many cells contain either

- `SAL`, **or**
- `PRE`

Comment: why not a simple second line `iVal2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("A:A"), "PRE")` and then add (or report both) variables as a total?

Comment: Because I'm going to be adding up to around 20 variables and do this for around 30 different columns, so will cut down a lot of work if I can get it all into one line!

Comment: How about reading the values of the column into an array? Then you can loop, add conditions and so on?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? If you are using 2007 and above doesn't it have a `CountIfs` function? Regardless, if you are looking for the fastest solution then doing JPs solution would probably be the fastest, you would have to do a test to find out though, sometimes excel is faster sometimes just doing loops in VBA is faster.

Comment: Im using 2010, doesn't the CountIfs function only work if all criteria are true, not if each one?

Comment: *"Im using 2010, doesn't the CountIfs function only work if all criteria are true, not if each one?"* Yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quickest way would just be to do 2 COUNTIFs:

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "SAL") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "PRE")
```

Comment: +1, this is your best approach as the CountIf can only accept one parameter.

Comment: This works great but in the long run i will be ending up with a lot of variable so trying to find a more efficient method, great intermediate method though!

Comment: @MattDonnan it is actually possible to feed COUNTIF more than one test, see above.

Comment: @brettdj No idea you could use the {} to add more values, it's not in the documentation, really good though. +1

Comment: Won't this count a cell that contains SAL and PRE twice?

Comment: Is there any way to use list of value with {arg1, arg2, ... } ?
the symbol { is identified as invalid character....

Comment: Facing the same error Mario. Couldn't find a solution. pExcludedItems = Sum(CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, colKeep), .Cells(pNumLinDadaStd, colKeep)), {"E", "E_"}))

Answer (score 21):

You could use the `VBA` equivalent of a standard COUNTIF formula (which can take more than one argument). This can be expanded as required

**Standard Formula**
`=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A, {"SAL","PRE"}))`

**VBA Equivalent**
    `MsgBox Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(A:A,{""PRE"",""SAL""}))")`

Comment: +1 Far and away the best answer so far!  Might pay to add VBA option to pass an array of strings `MsgBox Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(A:A,{""" & Join(v, """,""") & """}))")
`

Comment: @chrisneilsen thx - and excellent suggestion on the string array.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use the `CountIfs` function?

Example:

```
Application.CountIfs(CR1_range, V_1, CR2_range, V_2, CR3_range, V_3, CR4_range, V_4)
```

Where CR1_range is obviously your range and V_1 is your variable

Edit: Ooops! Just seen that it must be a OR statement, my answer would only work for an AND statement (didn't delete for reference incase anyone is interested)

Answer (score 0):

Following worked well for me: -

```
Dim val1 as string, val2 as string

val1 = "value1"
val2 = "value2"    

count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ThisWorkbook.Names("firstname").RefersToRange, val1 , ThisWorkbook.Names("secondname").RefersToRange, val2)
```

This [webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-named-ranges) helps regarding Named Ranges in Excel.