# How to CountIf in multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
x = 0
For Each cell in Sheets("01").Range("A:A").Cells
If cell.Value = "aaa" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "bbb" Then
x = x+1
End If
Next cell
MsgBox x
```

Is there a shorter way, pls ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Countif With Multiple OR Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726627/countif-with-multiple-or-criteria)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with a formula, like this

(Excel 2007 or later)

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"aaa",B:B,"bbb")
```

(Excel 2003 or earlier)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="aaa")*--(B:B="bbb"))
```

Or, if you have to do it in VBA, use `Evaluate`

```
MsgBox Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(A:A,""aaa"",B:B,""bbb"")")

MsgBox Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=""aaa"")*--(B:B=""bbb""))")
```

---

**EDIT**  based on your comment

If `rDat` and `rSec` are `Range`'s, and `ct` is the sheet `CodeName` do it like this

```
Dim rDat As Range
Dim rSec As Range
Set rDat = ct.[A:A]
Set rSec = ct.[B:B]
ct.Range("C6").Value = Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & rDat.Address(, , , True) & " ,""a""," & rSec.Address(, , , True) & ",""1"")")
```

---

If `ct` is the sheet `Name`, use this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDat As Range
Dim rSec As Range
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ct")
Set rDat = ws.[A:A]
Set rSec = ws.[B:B]
ws.Range("C6").Value = Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & rDat.Address(, , , True) & " ,""a""," & rSec.Address(, , , True) & ",""1"")")
```

If `rDat` and `rSec` are strings, use this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rDat As String
Dim rSec As String
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ct")
rDat = "ct!A:A"
rSec = "ct!B:B"
ws.Range("C6").Value = Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(" & rDat & " ,""a""," & rSec & ",""1"")")
```

---

Another option (for `rDat`, `rSec` as ranges)

```
ct.Range("C6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rDat, "a", rSec, "1")
```

Comment: Chris, I tried `ct.Range("C6").Value = Evaluate("=COUNTIFS(rDat,""a"",rSec,""1"")")` an got #NAME error. ct is a sheet, rDat and rSec are defined ranges. Excel 2010