# Color an Excel tab based on column value test

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that has multiple columns and rows of data. One column in particular, lets call it column 'L' will mostly have these 2 values:

- #N/A
- 0

It could however, have other values. What I want is I want VBA code that checks the values in this column and if it does not equal one of the two items above, change the color of the tab to red.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub CheckColumn()
Dim i
For i = 3 to 4001
If Cells(i, 12).Value <> xlErrNA And Cells(i, 12).Value <> "0" Then GoTo NoColor
Next i
With Activeworkbook.Activesheet.Tab
.Color = 255
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
Exit Sub
NoColor:
End Sub
```

But what I have doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas/suggestions/assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Bebause `xlErrNA` is not the correct check for a #N/A value (equivalent to using `NA()`)

Try a single shot formula such as this (see [Countif With Multiple OR Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726627/countif-with-multiple-or-criteria))

```
Sub CheckColumn()
If Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIF(K3:K4001,{""=0"",""#N/A""}))") <> 3998 Then
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab
.Color = 255
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Just fyi, on your answer you are missing an 'End If'

But with the link you provided I was able to figure it out:

```
For I = 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Activeworkbook.Worksheets(I).Select
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K2:K4000"), "0") + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K2:K4000"), "#N/A")
If iVal = 3999 Then
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab
.Color = 255
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
Next I
```

Again, thanks for your info - it was greatly appreciated.

Thanks!