# What is the proper syntax for countifs in VBA where one argument has OR criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I really have two questions:

1. Why is this line okay-

`Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing")`

But this isn't?

`Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("L:L"), "11", (Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing")`

When I try to add that extra criteria to the front, I get an error that says there is an expected parenthesis in place of the comma at this part-
`(Range(:AF:AF"),`

When I add the extra criteria to the end, it doesn't seem to have a problem with it. Very grumpy little thing.

2. The reason I ask is that I've been stuck trying to add an argument to the code that uses OR statements, but I'm not sure of the proper syntax. I'm trying to count all students who are at a certain grade level that are in a certain group and who are "Passing."

I've tried several different things, including this:

`Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing", Range("L:L"), "<>" "7" Or "8")`

and this

`Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing", Range("L:L"), "9" Or "10" Or "11" Or "12")`

The last one was the closest I've gotten, as it actually gives a value of zero instead of an error in the code, but I'm still not quite there.
I also tried an if-then statement at the beginning to weed out the grade I needed initially, but that WAY didn't work and gave me all kinds of runtime errors that made my head hurt.

I know that the problem is in the OR arguments because this line works:

`AlgAdv = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing", Range("L:L"), "9")`

I saw several posts about countifs formulas within Excel, but fewer about countifs in VBA. Of those, I saw only one that referenced an OR argument but the answer was not clear to me.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", _
                                                Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing", _
                                                Range("L:L"), ">=9", _
                                                Range("L:L"), "<=12")
```

Comment: This helped the most. I couldn't use this logic because one of the conditions is alphanumeric (so it wouldn't be recognized by the "<=" command. However, your suggestion helped me figure out a fix that worked for me, which was     Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("AF:AF"), "GroupA", Range("AJ:AJ"), "Passing", Range("L:L"), "<>8", Range("L:L"), "<>7")

Comment: I tried to format that last line above as code using the ticks, but I totally failed. Sorry!

Comment: Isn't it and AND logic? An OR logic was requested. I tried a solution using {} to pass several arguments into Countif but it complains invalid character. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes it is an AND'ed combination, but the OR is implemented by the  "LL between 9 and 12" (so 9,10,11,12 all satisfy the condition)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726792/11437092 (unless this is already one you've seen, of course).

It seems that you'd be able to use separate COUNTIF functions according to the number of OR arguments you need, and then simply add them together. May not be the most efficient way to do this, however.

Comment: I did see that; thank you! However, the way I read that, I would have had to do it for every condition so I would have had COUNTIFS(A, B, C)+COUNTIFS(A,B,D) + COUNTIFS (A, B, E)... etc for all five conditions, and THEN I would have had to replicate that in each of my 35 arguments and that seemed like so much code that I thought there must be an easier way!

Comment: I completely agree - certainly not ideal for efficiency!