# VBA Countifs multiple criteria return 0 - parameters from cells

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I would like to write a VBA Code which counts records in different excel tables with different criterias.
Parameters are recorded in a mapping table which will define the range and the criteria.

The following parameters will be recorded:

**column_number** of the range - long

**criteria** - string

I used the following format to retrieve the number of the records:

application.worksheetfunction.countifs(worksheet.columns(**columnnumber**),**criteria**)

the problem is when multiple criteria should be stored in the same cell.
in excel enviroment {"criteria1","criteria2"} works but not in VBA.

I tried to change the " to double "", also generate an array split by the commas ",".
But none of them returns back the count of the entries.

Any idea how this problem could be solved?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You could use [`Worksheet.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726627/countif-with-multiple-or-criteria