# VBA Countif with OR criteria

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I'm trying to use countif within VBA with multiple OR criteria and I found the old post below:

[Countif With Multiple OR Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726627/countif-with-multiple-or-criteria)

However when I try to use it in my project it returns "Compilation error: invalid character."

This is the line I'm trying to compile:

```
pExcludedItems = Sum(CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, colKeep), .Cells(pNumStdData, colKeep)), {"E", "E_*"}))
```

Also tried:

```
pExcludedItems = Sum(CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, colKeep), .Cells(pNumStdData, colKeep)), {""E"", ""E_*""}))
```

Can't find a solution elsewhere. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try the late bound `pExcludedItems = Application.Sum(Application.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, colKeep), .Cells(pNumStdData, colKeep)), [{"E", "E_*"}]))`. Also, Instead of `[{"E", "E_*"}]` you could use `Array("E", "E_*")`.

Comment: @VBasic2008: That is a valid answer. You may want to put that as an answer?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Thanks but I'm still trying to figure out how it works, at least how I see it working and why it doesn't work with `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: when you use `Application.WorksheetFunction`, with certain functions and certain scenarios, the code actually stops and goes into debugging mode. When you use `Application.`, it no longer stops with the debug and return the value or the error; whichever is applicable and the code continues to run.

Answer (score 3):

### Sum-up Countif Results in VBA

- You can use the late-bound:

  ```
  pExcludedItems = Application.Sum(Application.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, colKeep), .Cells(pNumStdData, colKeep)), [{"E", "E_*"}]))
  ```
- Also, Instead of `[{"E", "E_*"}]` you could use (the common):

  ```
  Array("E", "E_*")
  ```
- Note that `Sum` is needed only because you have multiple criteria. If there is only one criterion, you would rather use, e.g. the simple:

  ```
  pExcludedItems = Application.CountIf(rg, "E")
  ```

**A Practical Example**

- Copy the following to a standard module in a new workbook.
- Write some strings, some being just `E` and some being `E_*` (e.g. `E_One`, `E_Two` etc.), in column `C` of `Sheet1`.
- Monitor the results printed in the `VBE Immediate window` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1" ' Tab Name
    Const fRow As Long = 2 ' First Row
    Const Col As Long = 3 ' Column 'C'
    ' You cannot use a constant in the following line.
    Dim cCrit As Variant: cCrit = Array("E", "E_*") ' [{"E","E_*"}] '
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Last Row
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < fRow Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
    
    ' Range
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, Col), ws.Cells(lRow, Col))
    
    ' Print to the immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    
    ' Get result.
    Dim pExcludedItems As Long
    pExcludedItems = Application.Sum(Application.CountIf(rg, cCrit))
    Debug.Print "Result:   : " & pExcludedItems

    ' CountIf returns an array of counts (criteria is an array).
    Dim cCount As Variant: cCount = Application.CountIf(rg, cCrit)
    Debug.Print "CountArray: " & Join(cCount, ", ")
    
    ' Sum returns the sum of the elements of the array.
    Dim cSum As Long: cSum = Application.Sum(cCount)
    Debug.Print "Sum       : " & cSum

End Sub
```